# Display Image as Map and that can behave like default mapview(map)

Tags: android, image, dictionary, overlay

I need to show an image which is actually a map with coloured areas, also I need to be able to:

1. zoom in and out using two fingers
2. scroll the image as it is bigger than screen
3. Put marker on image, also scroll marker with respect to image and also i can click on marker.

I searched many hours, tried many approaches: 
1. Write a class that extends View, and display a Bitmap, I found a thread in the forum about it, but there is no zoom, and the scroll is not natural. 
2. Use a WebView to display HTML file that contains the image, so there is zoom and scroll functionalities, however, I cannot control the limit of zoom in/out, also, when the user clicks, I'm not sure if I can get the position on the image map by adding scrollX, scrollY with touchX, touchY. As the image may be scaled up/down, also, there may be paddings that WebView adds to its content.

This really drives me crazy, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always use place markers to show areas on map....so why to convert map to image?

Comment: No, i think you are on wrong way.
I want to display image (which is like custom map)and i want put marker on that. no actual Map(Google Map)

Comment: I want to do the same thing, and I am just looking into it.  Seems like this should be possible.  Let me know if you find anything.  I wonder if mapView.setBackground(Drawable d) would do anything...

Comment: hey Bipin, Have you got the solution of this question ?? It would be really appreciable if you will share ?

Comment: Hi Nibha, I had done that using HTML and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had sloved this new feature using HTML & jQuery.